# hasManyThrough on same models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have two classes **User** and **Message**,

I'm trying to get the replies to the user's messages from the user class thus

in the user class

```
public function replies()
{
   return $this->messages->replies; 
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work so I'm trying the hasManyThrough operation

```
public function replies() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Message::class,Message:class,'reply_id','user_id','id');
}
```

This doesn't work either because of a unique table issue

What's the best way to perform this operation?

Should I just use a raw get?

```
public function replies()
{
    return Message::whereIn('reply_id', $this->messages->pluck('id'))->get() 
}
```

***Bare in mind I may also want to perform pagination and ordering features***

Comment: you want to get all replies for all messages from user model?

Comment: @aimme that is correct

Comment: how about using 'with' ?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `hasManyThrough()` when it is only a one to many relationship?

What I would do in your case is within the User object use `$this->hasMany('\App\Models\Message')`.

Then within the Message object use `$this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User')`

Then from your User object you would be able to do `$user->messages->replies`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

**Example**

The User object:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function messages() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Message');
    }
}
```

The Message object:

```
class Message extends Model {

    public function user() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Then within a controller function of some kind for example you can do:

```
$user = User::with('messages')->findOrFail(1);
```

Which would return the User object with the messages which is it associated with.

So then you could do:

```
$user->messages->replies
```

Comment: I don't think you have it correct I'm trying to get the Replies by "other users" to his message(s). I thought by using hasmanythrough i'd use the reply_to as a foreign key on itself but without aliases I get issues